# Multiple CSS and ids in CakePHP

Tags: php, css, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP and modifying a theme with multiple CSS and ids is a problem.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='prettyPhoto-css'  href='style/prettyPhoto5b31.css?ver=4.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />

<link rel='stylesheet' id='uglyPhoto-css'  href='style/prettyPhoto5b31.css?ver=4.3.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

`$this->fetch('prettyPhoto5b31');` is used to fetch the CSS file from the webroot, but how do I call both or more IDs in the header of the layout?

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 $this->fetch('css');
```

to fetch the css files.